# Can anyone give a particular example, to illustrate the Difference between the terms 'joint distribution' and 'multivariate distribution'?

Tags: probability

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7269/255062) is discussing "the Difference between the terms 'joint distribution' and 'multivariate distribution'", where I cannot get the points.

Can anyone give a particular example, such as coin tossing or normal distribution, to illustrate that?

For example, there are 2 coins that have 10% and 20% probability of Head respectively.

toss them simultaneously, 10 times, and then we'll get a sequence of sets 
 like ({1,0},{0,0},...), in a length of 10.

in this particular case, what is the Difference between joint distribution and bivariate distribution?

if this is not a appropriate case, please feel free introduce any other cases, such as dice tossing, bivariate distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear, there is no mathematical difference between the terms: they describe the same object. However, they have slightly different connotations. Typically, a multivariate distribution is reserved for cases when one *starts* with a random vector in $\mathbb R^n$, in which case its distribution is called *a multivariate distribution*. The adjective *multivariate* simply means that we are working with random vectors. In essence, you are thinking of there being one random object, that happens to have several components (the components of the vector).

On the other hand, using the phrasing of *joint distribution* means that you have been studying two (or more) random objects separately from one another (considering their individual distributions, etc.) and you are then studying how the randomness relates between them. In the most common case, you have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ (meaning that you have functions $X,Y\colon \Omega\to\mathbb R$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space). Then, you can form a random vector $V=(X,Y)$. Note that $V\colon \Omega\to\mathbb R^2$, so that the distribution of $V$ would be called a multivariate distribution (by the first paragraph) if one was interested primarily in $V$, but would be called the *joint distribution* if one cares more about $X$ and $Y$.